# Undefined behaviour or gcc optimization bug

Tags: c++, optimization, g++, undefined-behavior

**The question is did we introduce undefined behaviour that trips optimizer, or can we file a bug report against gcc?**

Sorry for lack of better title, but it's quite fragile and we are almost sure that this is a bug. The minimal example is not our favourite design but it's based on production code that crashed:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    Node(Node* parent) {
        if(parent) {
           parent->child_ = this;
        }
    }
    Node* child()
    {
        return child_;
    }
    Node* child_ = nullptr;
};

void walk(Node* module, int cleanup) {
    if(module != nullptr) {
        if(!cleanup) {
            std::cerr << "No cleanup";
        }
        walk(module->child(), cleanup);
        if(cleanup) {
            delete module;
        }
    }
}

int main (){
    Node* top = new Node(nullptr);
    Node* child = new Node(top);
    walk(top,1);
}
```

Compiled with `-O1 -foptimize-sibling-calls -ftree-vrp`. Godbolt example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4VijKb

Program crashes calling `module->child()` when module is `0x0`. Inspecting assembler we noticed that `if (module != nullptr)` is skipped at the beginning of `walk`. There is a check for `cleanup` and call to `work` seems to be unconditional, which results in trying to pull `child_` from an invalid pointer.

The check is reestablished in assembly (and code seems to work) if:

1. Any of the two optimizations over `-O1` is taken away.
2. Body of `if(!cleanup)` is removed. (No side effect from `cerr`)
3. Body of `if(cleanup)` is removed. (Memory leak, but I think it counts as observable behaviour change)
4. `walk` is called before "No cleanup" `if`. (Operation order)
5. `cleanup` type is changed to `bool` from an `int`. (Type change - but no observable behaviour change, I think).
6. Insertion of unconditional `cerr << "text";` before and `if(!cleanup)`. (Also an observable change.)

It seems like a weird combination of tail-recursion and `nullptr` check removal that resulted in wrong code. Possibly `walk` got split into sibling functions based on `cleanup` checks and got stitched wrongly(?).

Two candidates for UB were:

1. Hinting compiler that `module` is non-`nullptr`, but I don't see a way compiler could infer the result.
2. Using `int` in `bool` context, but it's legal AFAIK.

FWIW `clang` seems to produce correct run-time, `gcc 8.3` also has the assembly for the check present. `9.1` and `trunk` not. We don't have any gcc expert at hand, so we had no idea why optimizer could be misled.

Comment: I can't see how skipping `if (variable != nullptr)` is not a bug  unless the if body was completely removed as unreachable.  (Or 'variable' can be proven as always nonzero.)  That kind of check is used all the time.

Comment: Wow. It does look like a compiler bug. I can't see anything wrong with this code.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it looks like, according to godbolt coloring (no assembly expert here, I can be wrong) that the null check is done at the end of the function, in line 20. Am I wrong?

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts Yes. I looks like tail-call version for when `cleanup` is `false`. It makes much sense. Check `cleanup`, if false jump to `L3` -  print, and pull `module->child_` into `module_` (`%rbx`), and since cleanup does not change, you can simply start looping, `while(module != nullptr)`, omitting 2nd `if`. That part is quite clever, even though the example never uses it.

Comment: @luk32 a bit too clever maybe. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does look like a GCC bug. I've been staring at this code for a while, and I can't find anything wrong with it whatsoever.

This is also reproducible with `gcc`, not just `g++`. It might be easier for the GCC developers to investigate if you write the minimal version of this in C. This C code reproduces the issue for me on GCC 9.1.0 with `-O1 -foptimize-sibling-calls -ftree-vrp`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    struct Node* child;
};

void walk(struct Node* module, int cleanup)
{
    if (module == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    if (!cleanup) {
        puts("No cleanup");
    }
    walk(module->child, cleanup);
    if (cleanup) {
        free(module);
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Node* node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node->child = NULL;
    walk(node, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've bisected it and reported https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90949

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks for performing due dilligence. Sorry for lagging with official report, but I got caught by holidays.

Comment: Just for the record, please: In the code in your answer, I am desperately looking for something smelly or on the edge of UB or such that might confuse GCC into misbehaviour. However, I cannot find anything. This could actually (semantically) be production code that I would write exactly the same way. I am honestly too unexperienced to follow the explanations in the GCC bugtracker. Could you please enlighten me...?

Comment: It's valid C and a miscompilation by GCC.